# How to install drivers for macbook pro 2018?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, compiling, make, macbook-pro

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 together with MacOS on my MBP 2018.

Now I'm trying to install the drivers from [MCMrARM](https://github.com/MCMrARM/mbp2018-bridge-drv), but running the Makefile gives me this:

> make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/build M=/home/hcpieck/mbp2018-bridge-drv modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic'
> arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
> make[1]: gcc: Command not found
> CC [M]  /home/hcpieck/mbp2018-bridge-drv/pci.o
> /bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
> make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:275: /home/hcpieck/mbp2018-bridge-drv/pci.o] Error 127
> make[1]: ***
> [Makefile:1734: /home/hcpieck/mbp2018-bridge-drv] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic'
> make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc: Command not found` means that `gcc` is not installed.

Run

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

to install required packages.

Comment: YES, that did the trick!

Thank you for you quick response Pilot6!

Comment: I have tried this approach without success with a macbook pro 2016.